# Where to ask questions about BIOS

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where is the best place to ask about BIOS problems?

Server Fault or Super User?

Comment: I thought this was asking about biographies, in which case [history.se] or [literature.se] would be best ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Most likely Super User** for general computer help.

Server Fault is more about managing information technology systems in a business environment.

You can find out what any site is about by clicking the 'help' menu and reading [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)